# I cannot `$_GET['id']` from URL

Tags: php

I try to use the update method from bootstrap modal, but when I click edit and url appears in this way `http://localhost/../pages/typography#edit?id = 15`.
I can not $ _GET ['id']
The error is, the indeterminate index

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail about what the `id` variable does? Have you considered using the javascript `fetch` method? Is the `id` variable an offset or limit of some sort, like the next 15 items in the index, or to only deliver 15 items?

Comment: I try this method with bootstrap modal , just i change the url when i click edit button, but server has get just part to #

Comment: Does the javascript running on the page need to access the `id` in the URL?

Answer (score 2):

Try `http://localhost/../pages/typography?id=15#edit`

The hash part (everything after `#`) is typically not sent to the server for processing. Anything you want your server to receive needs to be before the `#` symbol.

Comment: I need to use # because I don't want to refresh the page

Comment: If you don't want to refresh the page, how do you expect PHP to be called? If you're using Javascript to make a request to the server in the background, then simply don't send the `#edit` part.

Answer (score 1):

This URL `http://localhost/../pages/typography#edit?id = 15` ends after `#`

So, your server gets URI `/../pages/typography`

The structure or URL is:

`protocol`://`domain_name`/`URI`#`anchor`

Anchor (after `#`) can be proceeded on client side with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the one of the easiest ways to acomplish this is to send an AJAX request to your server using GET. Assuming that your page doesnt change based on the change or sending of the `id` variable, the following code will work.

Javascript:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "typography?id=" + id, true);
xhttp.send();
```

If your page does change by sending the `id` variable, then your page would have to reload. If that is a no-go you would have to implement a way for the PHP would return a JSON file with the data then your javascript on the gape would have to change the HTML based on the JSON data. This is better long term but is unnecessary to implement for small projects.